# Could not cast value of type 'UIButton' to 'NSURL'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, nsurl

I am working on a Udacity course for building iOS apps.  I have come across this problem in the connection/segue between the two screens of the course app and can't seem to find answers on the Udacity forum. I've gone back and checked my steps so really don't know why its happening. It is shown in the attached screen capture.

[image: screencapture]

The problem is baffling and I'd like to get through this before proceeding with the rest of the course.

Comment: why are you Casting UIButton into NSURL ???

Comment: sender is `UIButton`, not URL, I would suggest, that you need, for example, what is UIButton's text, need more details.

Comment: let recordedAudioURL= audioRecorder.url;  you can get URL like this ,,,

Comment: The solution strongly depends on the source of the segue. It seems that the segue is connected to a button rather than be called programmatically from the audio recording delegate method.

Comment: "Sender as! URL" changed to "audioRecorder.url" is working. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

when creating the segue you connected it from the button to the destination view controller, so it will crash because the sender is a UIButton. To fix this issue, first remove your segue. Then create a new one from the view controller to the destination view controller (with the same name you had previously).